# How to retrieve adwords reports to datatable using api adwords in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

I'm working on API using Google Adwords to retrieve adgroup performance data, when I use selector and select fields, I'm able to download reports in Excel sheets.

But I'm not getting how to retrieve ad group performance data and append to datatable using asp.net C#. which method I need to use to append into datatable? Is there any other way that I can get values and fields from ReportDefinition?

Answer (score 0):

`ReportDefinition` has a property called `downloadFormat`. You can set that to DownloadFormat.XML then you will get the string result in xml format, then you can parse that into json or C# object as you wish.